# How Do I Reset Modules to Default

Tags: fedora, kernel-modules

Bad form, but I attempted to install a custom module from a project that didn't support an uninstall target.

Now I'm getting odd behaviors with kernel panics and brightness zero on boot.

How can I reset modules? Is there a way to identify modules not default?

Comment: You probably don't. You probably have to manually remove the ones you manually installed. (Circumventing package management is a recipe for a bad time.)

Comment: Ok, I suppose, if I must, how do I get the right module?

Comment: What do you mean "get the right module"?

Comment: An existing one was overwritten.